# Error while Installing Chef Server

Tags: chef-infra

I am trying to install Open source chef server on my Linux machine. After I download and configure the server by using this command. `sudo chef-server-ctl reconfigure`.
It doesn't properly configure and got this error.

```
execute[/opt/chef-server/embedded/bin/chpst -u chef_server -U chef_server /opt/chef-server/embedded/bin/rabbitmqctl wait /var/opt/chef-server/rabbitmq/db/rabbit@localhost.pid] action run
================================================================================
Error executing action `run` on resource 'execute[/opt/chef-server/embedded/bin/chpst -u chef_server -U chef_server /opt/chef-server/embedded/bin/rabbitmqctl wait /var/opt/chef-server/rabbitmq/db/rabbit@localhost.pid]'
================================================================================


Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
------------------------------------
Expected process to exit with [0], but received '2'
---- Begin output of /opt/chef-server/embedded/bin/chpst -u chef_server -U chef_server /opt/chef-server/embedded/bin/rabbitmqctl wait /var/opt/chef-server/rabbitmq/db/rabbit@localhost.pid ----
STDOUT: Waiting for rabbit@localhost ...
pid is 10404 ...
STDERR: Error: process_not_running
---- End output of /opt/chef-server/embedded/bin/chpst -u chef_server -U chef_server /opt/chef-server/embedded/bin/rabbitmqctl wait /var/opt/chef-server/rabbitmq/db/rabbit@localhost.pid ----
Ran /opt/chef-server/embedded/bin/chpst -u chef_server -U chef_server /opt/chef-server/embedded/bin/rabbitmqctl wait /var/opt/chef-server/rabbitmq/db/rabbit@localhost.pid returned 2


Resource Declaration:
---------------------
# In /opt/chef-server/embedded/cookbooks/chef-server/recipes/rabbitmq.rb

 80:   execute "/opt/chef-server/embedded/bin/chpst -u #{node["chef_server"]["user"]["username"]} -U #{node["chef_server"]["user"]["username"]} /opt/chef-server/embedded/bin/rabbitmqctl wait #{rabbitmq_data_dir}/rabbit@localhost.pid" do
 81:     retries 10
 82:   end
 83: 



Compiled Resource:
------------------
# Declared in /opt/chef-server/embedded/cookbooks/chef-server/recipes/rabbitmq.rb:80:in `from_file'

execute("/opt/chef-server/embedded/bin/chpst -u chef_server -U chef_server /opt/chef-server/embedded/bin/rabbitmqctl wait /var/opt/chef-server/rabbitmq/db/rabbit@localhost.pid") do
  action "run"
  retries 0
  retry_delay 2
  guard_interpreter :default
  command "/opt/chef-server/embedded/bin/chpst -u chef_server -U chef_server /opt/chef-server/embedded/bin/rabbitmqctl wait /var/opt/chef-server/rabbitmq/db/rabbit@localhost.pid"
  backup 5
  returns 0
  cookbook_name :"chef-server"
  recipe_name "rabbitmq"
end




    Running handlers:
    [2015-01-12T18:32:00+05:30] ERROR: Running exception handlers
    Running handlers complete

    [2015-01-12T18:32:00+05:30] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
    [2015-01-12T18:32:00+05:30] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /opt/chef-server/embedded/cookbooks/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
    Chef Client failed. 19 resources updated in 53.22000489 seconds
    [2015-01-12T18:32:00+05:30] ERROR: execute[/opt/chef-server/embedded/bin/chpst -u chef_server -U chef_server /opt/chef-server/embedded/bin/rabbitmqctl wait /var/opt/chef-server/rabbitmq/db/rabbit@localhost.pid] (chef-server::rabbitmq line 80) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '2'
    ---- Begin output of /opt/chef-server/embedded/bin/chpst -u chef_server -U chef_server /opt/chef-server/embedded/bin/rabbitmqctl wait /var/opt/chef-server/rabbitmq/db/rabbit@localhost.pid ----
    STDOUT: Waiting for rabbit@localhost ...
    pid is 10404 ...
    STDERR: Error: process_not_running
    ---- End output of /opt/chef-server/embedded/bin/chpst -u chef_server -U chef_server /opt/chef-server/embedded/bin/rabbitmqctl wait /var/opt/chef-server/rabbitmq/db/rabbit@localhost.pid ----
    Ran /opt/chef-server/embedded/bin/chpst -u chef_server -U chef_server /opt/chef-server/embedded/bin/rabbitmqctl wait /var/opt/chef-server/rabbitmq/db/rabbit@localhost.pid returned 2
    [2015-01-12T18:32:00+05:30] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

Answer (score 3):

This error is caused by not following one of the Chef Server pre-requisites ("Apache Qid" section): http://docs.chef.io/server/install_server_pre.html

Solution:

service qpidd stop

chkconfig --del qpidd

Answer (score 1):

This generally means that your server doesn't have a valid and resolvable FQDN. This tends to make RabbitMQ unhappy.

Answer (score -1):

I tried a lot for this issue. I did lot of google search. Finally I got 1 solution.

**RabbitMQ service runs on 5672 port.** But this port is used by some other service. So I run to check is any services running on 5672 port using following command:

```
netstat -nltp | grep 5672
```

I killed service having port 5672 using following command :

```
sudo kill `sudo lsof -t -i:5672`
```

Then I run the sudo chef-server-ctl reconfigure again and it worked as expected.